# Bootstrap defaults on HTML tags

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Does bootstrap define any properties on any HTML tags?

If yes, will `normalize.css` or `reset.css` remove those properties?

Comment: You have a much better chance to get an useful answer, if your title is a clear question. Your title looks more like a tag cloud. Answerers see 50 questions in a column and it is totally up to them, where do they click.

Answer (score 0):

If you use any css code already wrote by someone that is focused on certain zones (like on `margin` for example) the final `margin` property that you will see in browser is the last one.
In other words if you set for example `margin:0 auto;` and then call or copy paste bootstrap code that change the global margin property, browser will take bootstrap settings for global `margin`.

So using bootstrap then reset.css then you'll get a page with the properties of reset.css for basic tags and bootstrap properties for defined classes by bootstrap( because reset.css doesn't select certain classes)

Comment: @PeriNikhil Good luck!